# R: converting a factor into time and date

Tags: r

I am trying to convert a factor into a time and date
I tried:

```
library(anytime)

date1 <- as.factor("22:20:00 18-Apr-2018")
class(date1)
date1 <- anytime(date1)
class(date1)
date1
```

But it returns NA

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `anytime` won't cope with every possible format. Just use the standard datetime formatting functions - `as.POSIXct(date1, format="%H:%M:%S %d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: Thanks very much.